# Ошибка в определении количество элементов массива в C++

Tags: c++

```
// TestLesson.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>  
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int* size = new int;
    cin >> *size;
    cout << "Элементы массива: | ";
    char* arrayChar = new char[*size];
    for (int k = 0; k < *size; k++) {
        arrayChar[k] = 'a' + k;
        cout << arrayChar[k] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << strlen(arrayChar);
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Почему метод **srtlen()** выводит отве больше, чем реально заданных (заданных при объявлении)? И при чем не имеер значение какой массив: статический или динамический. Я использую Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Функция `strlen` предназначена для определения длин С-строк. Аргументом функции `strlen` может быть только указатель на начало С-строки. В противном случае поведение не определено.

С-строкой называется последовательность символов типа `char`, завершающаяся символом `'\0'`. У вас в коде эти требования соблюдены? Нет. Поэтому применение функции `strlen` в вашем коде вызывает *неопределенное поведение*. Что вы и наблюдаете.

К "определению количества элементов массива", упомянутому в заголовке вашего вопроса, функция `strlen` никакого отношения не имеет. Более того, в С++ нет встроенных средств для определению количества элементов массива, выделенного через `new []`.

В вашем коде вы и так знаете размер вашего массива - это `*size`. Тщательно берегите этот размер и пользуйтесь им везде, где он вам нужен. Разумеется, вместо "голого" массива вы можете воспользоваться `std::vector`, который будем сам хранить этот размер для вас.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем усложняете себе "жизнь"? Можно проще

```
int size = 0;
cin >> size;  // 
cout << "Элементы массива: | ";
char* arrayChar = new char[size + 1]; // не size, а на 1 больше
for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
      arrayChar[k] = 'a' + k;
      cout << arrayChar[k] << " | ";  
    }

cout << endl << size;  // это и есть количество элементов
```